# Can this be done in 1 line?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

Can this be done in 1 line with PHP?

Would be awesome if it could:

```
$out = array("foo","bar");
echo $out[0];
```

Something such as:

```
echo array("foo","bar")[0];
```

Unfortunately that's not possible. Would it be possible like this?

So I can do this for example in 1 line:

```
echo array(rand(1,100), rand(1000,2000))[rand(0,1)];
```

So let's say I have this code:

```
 switch($r){
      case 1: $ext = "com"; break;
      case 2: $ext = "nl"; break;
      case 3: $ext = "co.uk"; break;
      case 4: $ext = "de"; break;
      case 5: $ext = "fr"; break;
 }
```

That would be much more simplified to do it like this:

```
$ext = array("com","nl","co.uk","de","fr")[rand(1,5)];
```

Comment: It's not that it's static data. array() can be stuffed with variables too.

Comment: At first I was going to explain to @thetaiko that that's not the point, but this may not actually be the best example. The syntax limitation really comes up when you try to do something like `echo explode(',', $str)[0]`. It's about function calls, not array initialization.

Comment: @Angelo - right, but `array(...)` instantiates a new array.  If you know what you want to output, and you already have it, why bother instantiating a new array?

Comment: @thetaiko: I agree, they wouldn't waste their time making a feature like this because there's no logical need for it.

Comment: See my example, I'd like to do that in 1 line.

Comment: $out = array("foo", "bar"); echo $out[0];

Comment: duplicate of [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+access+array+return+function)

Comment: Have you tried `echo array_shift(array("foo", "bar"));`?

Comment: @Angelo - see my answer.  It doesn't use an array but it gets the job done like you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not check out the [array functions on the PHP site](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)?

Well, if you're picking a random element from the array, you can use [`array_rand()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

```
$ext = array_rand(array_flip(array("com","nl","co.uk","de","fr")));
```

Comment: @Angelo: Read Jonathon's explanation above.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo array_rand(array_flip(array('foo', 'bar')));
```

array flip takes an array and swaps the keys with the values and vice versa. array_rand pulls a random element from that array.

Comment: @webbiedave: That's why you use array_flip to switch keys and values... Then you can reference the array as `$arr[$thatKey]`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) a PHP language construct that allows the syntax below.

```
list( $first_list_element ) = array( "foo", ..... );
```

EDIT:

Still Yes, Missed the echo. [`Reset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) will return the first array item, which *might* not always be index 0, but if you create an `array` normally it will.

```
echo reset( array( "foo",... ) );
```

EDIT AGAIN:

After you updated your question I see that you want something that PHP just can't do well. I personally think it's a syntax design error of the PHP language/interpreter. If you just mean one-line you could do.

```
$array = array( .... ); echo $array[0];
```

Comment: But, he wants to print out the first item (using a simple line), not just set it to a variable.

Comment: I think current() always returns the first one. Which is not what I want. I want to pick for example a random from the array I just initiated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shorthand form to keep things on one line and avoid creating an array that will never be used again.

```
echo rand(0,1) ? rand(1,100) : rand(1000,2000);
```

Comment: Will this be possible? echo rand(0,2) ? rand(1,100), rand(1000,2000), rand(5000,6000);

Comment: `echo rand(0,1) ? rand(1,100) : rand(0,1) ? rand(1000,2000) : rand(5000,6000);`

Comment: @Angelo: Of course, if you want to make it more complicated you should write a function.  Keeping everything on one line doesn't always make for readable and efficient code.

Comment: @thetaiko: Look out! You have twice as much chance getting a 1-100 as you do 1000-2000 or 5000-6000.

Comment: @too much php: indeed you are correct - I simply extended my original answer without thinking too much about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your example may not be the best. The real syntax limitation here is that one can not immediately perform array access on the returned value of a function call, as in,

```
do_something_with(explode(',', $str)[0]);
```

And you pretty much can't get around it. Assign to a variable, then access. It's a silly limitation of PHP, but it's there.

You can technically do,

```
function array_access($array, $i) {
    return $array[$i];
}
do_something_with(array_access(explode(',', $str), 0));
```

But please don't. It's even uglier than an extra variable asignment.

*(Given the edit to the question, this no longer a sufficient answer. However, I will leave it up for reference.)*

Comment: This would be exactly what I want, but ofcourse like you said; it's kind of ugly code.

Answer (score 0):

```
print $a[ array_rand($a = array('com','nl','co.uk','de','fr')) ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Matchu's answer, this addresses the more general case, ie you have an array value that came from *somewhere*, be it a function call, an instantiated array, whatever.  Since the return value from an arbitrary function is the least specific case, I'll use a call to `some_function()` in this example.

```
$first_element = current(array_slice(some_function(), 0, 1));
```

So you could randomize it with

```
$random_element = current(array_slice(some_function(), rand(0,1), 1));
```

but in that case (as in many in php) there is a more specialized function for that; see @animuson's answer.

#### edited

changed array_shift() call to current() call: this is more efficient, because array_shift() will modify the intermediate array returned by array_slice().